# ¿ Cómo ejecuto un script de python desde php con wampserver en window?

Tags: php, python-3.x

Me gustaría poder ejecutar un script de python desde php con wampserver, el caso es que verán; pretendo generar un fichero con un script de python, el cual quiero ejecutarlo desde mi controlador en php.
En mi equipo tengo python3.9 instalado.

No me queda claro si hay que instalar python en el apache que tiene wampserver o qué es lo que se tiene que hacer para que el script funcione correctamente desde mi función de php.

Les dejo el código de mi función de mi controlador encargado de llamar a este script en python.

```
function generarExcelPython()
    {

        exec('py ' . __DIR__ . '/../mirutascript/miscript.py 2>&1', $output, $response);
        var_dump($response);
        var_dump($output);
        if ($response == 0) {        // Fichero creado exitosamente.
            $this->output
                ->set_content_type('xlsx')
                ->set_output(file_get_contents('./tmp/fichero.xlsx'));
        } // if
        else {
            $msg ="Error";
            var_dump($msg);
        } // else
    }
```

el error que me sale al ejecutar esta función de mi controlador, es el siguiente :

```
**  0 => string 'Traceback (most recent call last):' (length=34)
  1 => string '  File "mirutascript/miscript.py", line 3, in <module>' (length=89)
  2 => string '    import xlsxwriter' (length=21)
  3 => string 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'' (length=49) **
```

Estoy usando wampserver con  mysql,  php, en window.

El script por sí solo, sí me genera el fichero, pero al ejecutarlo con php, me da el anterior error mencionado.

El script de python

```
import xlsxwriter
import pymysql.cursors



connection = pymysql.connect(**DB_CONF) 

try:
# Creo un libro de trabajo (workbook) y le a�ado una hoja de trabajo (worksheet).
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('.tmp/pruebasIncidenciasPy2.xlsx') # LOCAL ruta absoluta
# workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('./tmp/total.xlsx') # SERVIDOR
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("ficheroExportado")

# Establesco la cabecera
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'bg_color': '#f48942', 'align': 'center'}) # Formato celda.

worksheet.write('A1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('B1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('C1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('D1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('E1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('F1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('G1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('H1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('I1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('J1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('K1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('L1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('M1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('N1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('O1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('P1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('Q1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('R1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('S1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('T1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('U1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('V1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('W1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('X1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('Y1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('Z1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('AA1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('AB1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('AC1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('AD1', 'campo1', cell_format)
worksheet.write('AE1', 'campo1', cell_format)



# Empezamos desde la primera celda de cada fila. Filas y columnas comienzan indexadas desde 0.
row = 1
col = 0

#Creo el cursor con el que recorrer la sentencia.
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
# Solicito los datos a guardar en la hoja.
sql = """ My query  """

cursor.execute(sql)
result = cursor.fetchall()

# tupla = ('2021-06-10','2021-06-15')
# cursor.execute(sql, tupla)

format2= workbook.add_format({'num_format' : 'dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss'})
cont = 0
# Iteramos cada dato y escribimos en el excel fila a fila.
# for id_averia, id_cajero_logico, numero_serie, duracion, estado_apertura_accion, fecha_modificacion , estado_de_cierre , usuarioAsignado in (result):
for id_averia, entidad, id_cajero_logico, numero_serie, cajero_desplazado, tipologia_de_incidencia, subtipologia_de_incidencia, status_de_incidencia, fecha_de_incidencia, duracion_de_la_incidencia, fecha_de_alta, estado_de_apertura, fecha_modificacion, estado_de_cierre, estado_de_vigia, usuario_asignado, numero_de_averia, fecha_de_actualizacion_carga, idEntidad, modelo_del_cajero, marca, sistema_operativo, estado_cajero, subtipo_de_escalado, fecha_cierre, comentario_averia in (result):

worksheet.write(row, col , id_averia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, entidad)
worksheet.write(row, col + 2, id_cajero_logico)
worksheet.write(row, col + 3, numero_serie)
worksheet.write(row, col + 4, cajero_desplazado)
worksheet.write(row, col + 5, tipologia_de_incidencia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 6, subtipologia_de_incidencia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 7, status_de_incidencia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 8, fecha_de_incidencia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 9, duracion_de_la_incidencia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 10, fecha_de_alta)
worksheet.write(row, col + 11, estado_de_apertura)
worksheet.write(row, col + 12, fecha_modificacion)
worksheet.write(row, col + 13, estado_de_cierre)
worksheet.write(row, col + 14, estado_de_vigia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 15, usuario_asignado)
worksheet.write(row, col + 16, numero_de_averia)
worksheet.write(row, col + 17, fecha_de_actualizacion_carga)
worksheet.write(row, col + 18, idEntidad)
worksheet.write(row, col + 19, modelo_del_cajero)
worksheet.write(row, col + 20, marca)
worksheet.write(row, col + 21, sistema_operativo)
worksheet.write(row, col + 22, estado_cajero)
worksheet.write(row, col + 23, subtipo_de_escalado)
worksheet.write(row, col + 24, fecha_cierre)
worksheet.write(row, col + 25, comentario_averia)

row += 1


# Cerramos la hoja
workbook.close()
except:
raise
finally:
#Por ultimo cerramos la conexi�n
connection.close()
```

Comment: Al parecer si está ejecutando el py, porque el error que estas obteniendo es: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlsxwriter'`. Significa que la instalación de python no está reconociendo `xlsxwriter`. Verifica que ese módulo esté instalado correctamente.

Comment: si no conoces python te recomiendo que entiendas que es un `virtualenv` primero, instala las librerias dentro del proyecto

Comment: @eaportugal, gracias por tu comentario, sí, tengo instalado el xlsxwrite, el script desde cmd sí, me genera el archivo, pero no me queda muy claro, si en el apache que viene con wampserver, debo se instalar python o estos módulos.

Comment: @EgonStetmann. gracias por tu comentario, lo haré.

Answer (score 0):

[Aquí te dice como para Linux, es el mismo principio/idea para Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19736494/4717133)

yo en lugar de usar `shell_exec` prefiero usar `exec`; pero te lo traduzco igual:

---

En PHP [utiliza la función shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php):

> Ejecutar un comando mediante el intérprete de comandos y devolver la salida completa como una cadena.
>
> La salida del comando ejecutado o null si ocurre un error o el comando no produce ninguna salida.
> Nota:
> Esta función puede devolver null cuando ocurre un error o cuando el programa no produce ninguna salida. No es posible detectar los fallos de ejecución usando esta función. exec() debería usarse cuando sea necesario el acceso al código de salida del programa.

```
<?php 

$command = escapeshellcmd('/usr/custom/test.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

En el archivo de Python `test.py`, verifique este texto en la primera línea: [(ver shebang explicar)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2429511/why-do-people-write-usr-bin-env-python-on-the-first-line-of-a-python-script/2429517):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

> Si tiene varias versiones de Python instaladas, /usr/bin/env
> asegúrese de que el intérprete utilizado sea el primero en su entorno
> $PATH. La alternativa sería codificar algo como
> #!/usr/bin/python; eso está bien, pero menos flexible.
>
> En Unix, un archivo ejecutable destinado a ser interpretado puede indicar
> ¡Qué intérprete usar con un #! al comienzo de la primera línea,
> seguido del intérprete (y las banderas que pueda necesitar).
>
> Si habla de otras plataformas, por supuesto, esta regla no
> aplicar (pero esa "línea shebang" no hace daño y le ayudará si alguna vez
> copie ese script en una plataforma con una base Unix, como Linux,
> Mac, etc.).

> Esto se aplica cuando lo ejecuta en Unix haciéndolo ejecutable
> (chmod + x myscript.py) y luego ejecutarlo directamente: ./myscript.py,
> en lugar de solo python myscript.py

Para [convertir un archivo ejecutable en plataformas de tipo Unix](http://nersp.nerdc.ufl.edu/%7Edicke3/nerspcs/chmod.html):

```
chmod +x myscript.py
```

También el archivo Python [debe tener los privilegios correctos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#37971) (ejecución para el usuario www-data/apache si el script PHP se ejecuta en el navegador o curl)
y/o debe ser "ejecutable". Además, todos los comandos del archivo `.py` deben tener los privilegios correctos.

Tomado [del manual de php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php#37971):

> Solo un recordatorio rápido para aquellos que intentan usar shell_exec en un
> plataforma de tipo Unix y parece que no puede hacer que funcione. PHP se ejecuta como
> el usuario web en el sistema (generalmente www para Apache), por lo que debe
> asegúrese de que el usuario web tenga derechos sobre los archivos o
> directorios que está intentando utilizar en el comando shell_exec.
> De lo contrario, no parecerá que esté haciendo nada.

Comment: agradezco su tiempo, pero no me queda muy claro, ahora no conseguí realizar lo que busco.

Comment: @Peponchez puedes ser mas especifico en tu comentario, no aporta nada.. que situacion presentas?

Comment: gracias por todo, pero hice lo que has comentado, puse #!rutaPython python, cambié a shell_exec , pero éste no retorna ningún mensaje, y mirando por internet busqué que había que instalar como una especie de modulo de python, pero no me queda muy claro si lo hice bien, pues no me funciona un simple fichero con un print("HOLA MUNDO WEB"). Y solo pretendo ejecutar un script que genera un excel, desde una función de php, pero nada.

Comment: intenta ejecutar el script python solo y dices que te sale}

Comment: ejecutando el script solo con el cmd sí que me genera lo que viene siendo el fichero, el problema que tengo es que al llamarlo desde php, por cierto tengo wampserver instalado, y dentro de este tiene apache 2.4.9 mysql 5.6.17 y php 5.5.12, tengo que instalar lo que viene siendo python en el servidor que viene con wampserver, lo hice pero no me funciona bien, también debería de instalar lo que viene siendo las librerías que uso como xlsxwriter, pymysql . Antes cuando solo ejecutaba el script con cmd me decía ese error pero instale con pip install las librerías y se generó pero desde cmd.

Comment: desde php se ejecuta con exec('argumentos cmd'); utilizando los comandos completos de python como argumebtos de cmd, php no necesita librerias... en este caso php llama a ejecucion la terminal del S. O y este a su vez llama al programa instalado,... en este caso python debe tener las librerias correctas...

Comment: Te agradezco tu tiempo y tus comentarios, pero el problema que tengo es que no sé muy bien en que parte tengo que instalar las librerías como  xlsxwriter, pymysql que uso para que se genera el excel, o si es necesario instalar estas.

Comment: si tu script es d python todas la librerias que uses para trabajar archivos y conectarte a base de datos debes instalarlas en pytho... por lo que veo php solo lo usas para ejecutar el comando de python, no veo que a php conectandoce a la base de datos ni veo a php creando el archivo excel... no entiendo tampoco cual es tu logica... por que quieres meter librerias en php que no usa php...

Comment: lo primero que debes hacer es lograr ejecutar el comando en php que ejecutara al script python, luego si requieres leer el archivo excel o trabajar con el desde php  y no puedes entonces creas una pregunta basada en ese problema, no lo combines las preguntas... son cosas distintas....